# How do I conditionally fill one cell based off content of two cells?

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

I need help with a formula for conditional formatting. I have two rows A and B. I want A to fill red if A is blank ***and*** B contains the text "Yes".

I know how to set it up to fill based off the B cell but I don't know how to only make it fill if the A cell is blank.

Answer (score 0):

An example of this exact scenario is on [Office's Support Page](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-a-formula-to-apply-conditional-formatting-fed60dfa-1d3f-4e13-9ecb-f1951ff89d7f).

> =C2="Y"
>
> The formula tests to see if the cells in column C contain “Y” (the
>   quotation marks around the Y tell Excel that this is text). If so, the
>   cells are formatted.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question of how to do it *if A is blank and B contains the text "Yes"*. You need to read the question carefully to ensure you answer all of it.

Answer (score 0):

[`AND`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AND-function-5f19b2e8-e1df-4408-897a-ce285a19e9d9) is a logical function which allows you to check multiple criteria. If all criteria are met, it returns TRUE.

[image]

```
=AND(ISBLANK(A1), B1="Yes")
```

The above formula checks to see if `A1` is black AND `B1` equals `Yes`. If both are true, the conditional format will be applied.

[image]